# Unable to Split the array element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, split, element

I am quite new to Javascript. I wanted to get the filename and extension from a specific folder. For that i am using ActiveXObject and going to the folder using GetFolder and then enumerating through each individual files. The code is given below.

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myFileNameArray = new Array;
var myFileNameArray = new Array;
function ReadFromFile()
{
    var i;
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fsofolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\\Users\\Divya.R");
var colFiles  = fsofolder.Files;
var fc = new Enumerator(colFiles);
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext() )
    { 
        msg += fc.item() + ";";
    }
myFilePathArray = msg.split(";");
for(i=0;i<=myFilePathArray.length;i++)
    {
        myFileNameArray[i] = myFilePathArray[i].split("\\");
    }
document.write(myFileNameArray[0]);
}
</script>
<body onload='ReadFromFile()'>
</body>
</html>
```

I will get the complete file path in myFilePathArray from each array element i should get the filename. For that I am trying to split again based on '/' and then thought to get the arraylength-1 th element. However the last document write return be a blank page. It doesnt split the myFilePathArray. Please let me know what is wrong with this.

Regards,

Div

Answer (score 0):

Since \ is an escape character it will be ignored. I have found a solution which worked for me. The code is given below.

```
var msg = "C:\\Users\\Divya.R\\Data.txt;C:\\Users\\Divya.R\\Test2.csv";
var regex = /\\/g;
var fileName="";
var FilePath = msg.replace(regex, "\\\\");
//document.write(FilePath);
var myArray1 = new Array;
var myArray2 = new Array;
myArray1 = FilePath.split(";");
myArray2 =myArray1[0].split("\\");
    for(var i=0;i<=myArray1.length-1;i++)
    {
         myArray2= myArray1[i].split("\\");
         fileName = fileName+myArray2[myArray2.length-1];



    }
//alert(myArray2[myArray2.length-1]);
alert(fileName);
```

Regards,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

A simple `substr` and `lastIndexOf` would suffice to get your parts:

```
var path = "C:\\Users\\Divya.R\\Data.txt";
var fileName = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
var ext = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); // txt
```